# In ruby, is there any operator similar to ||= for the assignment: a = b if !b.nil?

Tags: ruby, operators

Just as the title asks, is there an operator, or some snazzy one liner to do the above?

To clarify, if this is the first time `a` is being referenced, and `b` is `nil`, a shouldn't persist past the evaluation of `b` being nil.

Comment: Signature is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no operator that I know of. Your response is already one line ... If you really wanted you can change the if ! to unless.

Comment: hmm, now if only i knew enough about ruby syntax to do such in the assignment of an array =/
something = {a = b, c = d unless d.nil?; end} Doesn't quite work

Comment: You can't do that either. You'd have to build the array in pieces.

Comment: It's the same to do: a = b if b *or* something = {:a => b, :c => d} if d

Comment: Yea, but you can't have the if inside the hash as was suggested above. At least, that's how I read the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby local variables can spring into existence without a line assigning to them actually being executed:

```
a #=> NameError ...
if false
  a = 1
end
a #=> nil
```

Your snippet is equivalent to

```
if !b.nil?
  a = b
end
```

If b is nil, then the assignment is not executed, and from the previous example this will set the value of a to nil. If b is not nil then a is set to the value of b. So this (somewhat surprisingly) is actually the same as

```
a = b
```

But only if `a` doesn't exist yet, and thus a very error prone way of doing things. Don't do this!

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
a = b unless b.nil?
```

or:

```
b.nil? and a = b
```

They aren't they readable oneliners?

Comment: I was hoping there was an operator that could be used while constructing hashes inside curly braces, looks like i'll just have to build one in pieces.

Comment: But the point is: Do you really need such operator? IMHO, there may be very valid arguments against such practice: How will you refer to 'a' in the future if it may not exist? Will the semantics of that operator be something readable and genuinely usefull? I sincerily doubt that.